# Too many eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, terminology, definition

> For an $n \times n$ matrix, we can only have at most $n$ different eigenvalues.

Suppose I have $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2} & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Using characteristic equation $0 = \det(A - \lambda I) = \lambda^2 - \frac{1}{4}$, I get $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \pm \frac{1}{2}$.

This means I have either $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \frac{1}{2}$ or $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$. However, this gives me a total of $4 > n = 2$ eigenvalues.

Why am I getting so many eigenvalues? Shouldn't I get only 2?

Comment: You have two eigenvalues that you listed.  $\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$.  They each have algebraic multiplicity $1$.  Now... check to see the geometric multiplicity of each for practice (*geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue is always at least $1$ and is always at most the algebraic multiplicity, so even without checking we know it will be $1$*).  Note: $\lambda_1=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ is short hand for saying that $\lambda_1=\frac{1}{2}$ or $\lambda_1=-\frac{1}{2}$.  It is of course impossible for it to equal both simultaneously.

Comment: you get two eigen values, $+\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$. The eigen values satisfy the characteristic equation individually, not together.

Comment: Write $\lambda^2-{1 \over 4} = (\lambda-{1 \over 2})(\lambda+{1 \over 2})$, this is where the roots come from. Blindly applying $\pm$ to a number is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\lambda_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$. Note that if $\lambda$ is a root of $\det(A-\lambda I)$, the matrix $A - \lambda I $ is not invertible, hence there exists $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $(A- \lambda I)v = 0$, that is $Av = \lambda v$. So $\lambda$ **is an eigenvalue**. This is why we only count distinct eigenvalues, and we then talk about the dimension of their eigenspaces or their algebraic/geometric multiplicity.

Comment: What do you mean by "if $\lambda$ is a root of $\det(A-\lambda I)$, the matrix $A - \lambda I$ is not invertible"? Aren't all $\lambda$ roots of it?

Comment: Here $\lambda$ is just a variable. My point is, every root of the characteristic polynomial is an eigenvalue. Hence both $\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ are eigenvalues in your example.